# Nested Timelines jerk when individually manipulated later on

Tags: javascript, timeline, tween, gsap

I'm trying to create Timelines within Timelines where I can have an ability to manipulate each child Timeline afterwards.

These are results I have at this moment:

1. **[[Codepen]](http://codepen.io/skmasq/pen/JCrBi)** Initially child timeline **is paused**, but then `.play()` function is passed into parent timelines `.add()` function
2. **[[Codepen]](http://codepen.io/skmasq/pen/jyJHh)** Initially child timeline **is not paused** and the whole instance is passed into parrent timelines `.add()` function

As you can see when I press button `single restart` it jerks the animation and just shows the result, thus afterwards if one would want to call `.play()` function it would show only the result again, leaving the rest of animation un-shown.

Are there any reference to how achieve this is or any tutorials with best practices?